# Javascript == string comparison acting weird

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I have this JavaScript code:

```
if ( data == 'error_getting_solution_comments' )
{
    alert ("test");
}
```

And for some reason, the if statement does not match up with the string even if the data string has the same value.

Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see more code. Specifically we need to see when and how `data` is set.

Comment: It won't happen if in fact the variable **really** contains the same value.  Are you sure there aren't leading or trailing spaces, or something like that?

Comment: can you put a running sample (maybe on jsfiddle)?

Comment: Yeah, it's not the same value. There might be reasons as to why it would look like the same value, but still isn't. Point proven: http://jsfiddle.net/eRRBv/

Comment: Trimming the string ended up working - although I checked many times whether extra space could get there, and not sure how it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying isn't possible **unless** you're forgetting that JS is a case sensitive language. For example:

```
var data = "error_getting_solution_comments"

if (data == 'error_getting_solution_comments') //TRUE
{
    alert ("test");
}
if (data == 'Error_getting_solution_comments') //FALSE
{
    alert ("test");
}
```

If case isn't the issue, then the value of `data` doesn't equal `error_getting_solution_comments`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of 'data'? Maybe it is an object? Try this:

```
if(data.value == 'error_getting_solution_comments' )
{ 
alert("Sucess!");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**EDIT:**

This is wrong. Yes. Single inverted comma and double inverted comma does not make a difference except at certain places. Don't bother yourself.

---

**DO NOT** Try this code:

```
if ( data == "error_getting_solution_comments" )
{
   alert ("test");
}
```

Comment: You have to use double inverted comma there.

Comment: No, you don't.  Single quotes for strings are fine in JavaScript.